# sklearn k-means: Distance from point to cluster centre

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, distance, k-means

I am using sklearn k-means clustering and I would like to know how to calculate and store the distance from each point in my data to the nearest cluster, for later use. My code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.sparse as sp
from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import euclidean_distances
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.datasets.samples_generator import make_blobs

def learn(records):

    data = [getDataFromTransaction(t) for t in records]
    batch_size = 45
    X = np.array(data)
    centers = [[1, 1, 1], [-1, -1, -1], [1, -1, 1]]
    n_clusters = len(centers)
    #X, labels_true = make_blobs(n_samples=20, centers=centers, 
    cluster_std=0.7)
    ##############################################################################
    # Compute clustering with Means
    k_means = KMeans(init='k-means++', n_clusters=3, n_init=10)
    k_means.fit(X)
    k_means_labels = k_means.labels_
    k_means_cluster_centers = k_means.cluster_centers_
    k_means_labels_unique = np.unique(k_means_labels)
    colors = ['#4EACC5', '#FF9C34', '#4E9A06']
    plt.figure()
    plt.hold(True)
    for k, col in zip(range(n_clusters), colors):
            my_members = k_means_labels == k
            cluster_center = k_means_cluster_centers[k]
            plt.plot(X[my_members, 0], X[my_members, 1], 'w',
                    markerfacecolor=col, marker='.')
            plt.plot(cluster_center[0], cluster_center[1], 'o', markerfacecolor=col,
                    markeredgecolor='k', markersize=6)


    plt.title('KMeans')    
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.savefig('./'+str("clustering")+'k_.png')
    plt.show(0)
    plt.show()
```

Sorry for bad format, and thank you for any help you can provide

Answer (score 2):

In k-Means, points are assigned to the cluster which minimizes sum of squared deviations from the cluster center. Thus, all you have to do is take the Euclidean norm of the difference between each point and the center of the cluster to which it was assigned in k-Means.

Below is the pseudocode:

```
for i in NumClusters:
    dataInCluster = data[clusterLabels[cluster==i].rowNames,]
    distance = norm(dataInCluster-clusterCenter[i])
```

Then you can add the distances as an additional column in your data.